# How to cause memory fragmentation on a Linux based embedded device?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

**What am I trying to do:**
Answer: I am trying to create memory fragmentation on a Linux 2.6.31 based swapless embedded device.

**Why:**
Answer:I am trying to port some patches to Linux 2.6.31 that will defragment the fragmented memory. In order to test if those patches are working correctly I'd like to try to fragment the memory first.

I learnt that continuous allocation and deallocation of memory by apps can lead to fragmentation. Therefore I wrote these simple C programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, j = 0, randnum=0;
    while(1) {

        randnum = rand()%10000000;
        double *ptr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * randnum);

        for(j = 0 ; j < randnum; j++) {
            *(ptr+j) = (double)j+1;
        }

        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

==========

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, j = 0, randnum=0;
    int arr[6] = { 3072, 7168, 15360 , 31744, 64512, 130048}; 
    while(1) {

        for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {

            int *ptr = (int*) malloc(arr[i] * 93);  

            for(j = 0 ; j < arr[i] * 93 / sizeof(int); j++) {
                *(ptr+j) = j+1;
            }

            free(ptr);
        }
    }       
}
```

**How do I measure if memory is fragmented?:**
Answer:I look at the o/p of `/proc/buddyinfo`

**What do I need:?**
Can you suggest a better way to fragment the memory? Because those C programs work but very very slowly.

Comment: @Duck Without filling up the memory, malloc does not actually allocate the memory from the heap.

Comment: Do you have sysrq triggers available on your system? Why are allocating and immediately freeing the memory after you populate it? Does that loop even complete? You should always be able to satisfy any allocation request. Wouldn't it make more sense to allocate and randomly free certain segments until the memory is so fragmented that only progressively smaller requests can be satisfied?

Comment: @Matt Yes I have sysrq triggers enabled on the system. How would I (or can I) allocate memory and then free up **only** certain segments? What is the way to do that ?

Comment: instead of your free I would do something like this:

if(rand()%100 > 50) {
free(ptr);
}
50% chance to free memory. 50% chance to keep it allocated. You can modify the ratio if you want and modify the range of the chunks you are allocating. To me that seems like it would demonstrate fragmentation a lot better then what you are doing.

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to cause significant fragmentation in the sense of the buddy allocator by the method you are using.

The reason is that that buddy allocator works with *physical memory*. User space `malloc` works with *logical memory* and under the hood (via `sbrk` or `mmap(... MAP_ANON)`) will call `get_free_page` for allocation of single page. It thus does not require the *phyiscal memory* to be adjacent, i.e. the physical pages can at entirely different memory addresses but the MMU will make them appear together. Furthermore, userspace does not allocate with `GFP_ATOMIC` (or these days perhaps it's called `GFP_NOWAIT`) so it can simply swap things out to make them work.

What you will need to do is find something that will allocate kernel memory with `GFP_ATOMIC` more than 4k at a time. Sending and receiving large network packets is one way to do this in user space (even if these fragment, the fragment reassembly I believe needs a contiguous buffer). Better though would be to put in a simple for-test-purposes-only ioctl that allocates and frees kernel blocks (if there isn't one already).

*Historical note: bizarre as it may seem, the original linux buddy memory allocator was my first C program (rewritten by Linus before he accepted it), though last time I looked my email address at the time is still somewhere in `kmalloc.c`. I do not recommend this as an approach to learn C.*